# Second <aura:iteration> not working with object/array datasource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura-iteration

I have a Lightning component with two `<aura:iteration>`

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="invoices" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="invoiceLines" type="Object" />

<aura:iteration aura:id="invoiceList" items="{!v.invoices}" var="invoice">

  <c:lightningFormElementOutput label="Invoice ID" value="{!invoice.Name}" />
  <c:lightningFormElementOutput label="Person" value="{!invoice.Person__r.Name}" />
  <c:lightningFormElementOutput label="Status" value="{!invoice.Status__c}" />
  <c:lightningFormElementOutput label="Total" value="{!'£' + invoice.Total_Amount__c}" />

</aura:iteration>

<h3 class="slds-section__title">
    Invoice Lines ({!v.invoiceLines.length})
</h3>

<aura:iteration aura:id="invoiceLineList" items="{!v.invoiceLines}" var="invoiceLine">

  <c:lightningFormElementOutput label="Line ID" value="{!invoiceLine.Name}" />
  <c:lightningFormElementOutput label="Invoice ID" value="{!invoiceLine.Invoice__r.Name}" />
  <c:lightningFormElementOutput label="Description" value="{!invoiceLine.Description__c}" />

</aura:iteration>
```

The two datasources `invoices` and `invoiceLines` are set in the `doInit` method:

```
doInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    let params = {};
    params.appointmentId = cmp.get("v.recordId");
    helper.callAction(cmp, "c.getInvoices", params, function (invoices) {
        if (invoices) {
            cmp.set("v.invoices", invoices);
            var invoiceLines = [];
            invoices.forEach(i => {
                console.log('i.Invoice_Lines__r');
                console.log(i.Invoice_Lines__r);
                invoiceLines.push(i.Invoice_Lines__r);
            });
            console.log('invoiceLines');
            console.log(invoiceLines);
            cmp.set("v.invoiceLines", invoiceLines);
        }
    });
},
```

Each of the `console.log` statements returns expected data.

And notice the `H3` with `Invoice Lines ({!v.invoiceLines.length})` that outputs a value.

Yet the second `<aura:iteration>` does not render any values.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

invoiceLines ends up being a multidimensional array:

```
[ [ {  }, {  }, {  } ], [ {  }, {  }, ...] ]
```

While what you actually need is a single-dimension array. To do this, you need to concatenate the arrays together.

```
invoices.forEach(i => invoiceLines = invoiceLines.concat(i.Invoice_Lines__r));
```